# Can't add annotation EnableWebSocketMessageBroker

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-websocket

I've some spring boot REST API and I need add WebSocketController and WebSocketConfig for this controller to server, for working with REST API + websocket:

When I added annotation @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker to config and execute server - I've got some error

(Without @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker near config my server works, but, i think, that websocket willn't work without MessageBroker)

**application:**

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication

@SpringBootApplication
class SmartHouseServerApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<SmartHouseServerApplication>(*args)
}
```

**controller:**

```
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
class GreetingController {

    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("topic/hi")
    fun hello(string: String): String {
        return "hello"
    }

}
```

**config:**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
class WebSocketConfig : AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer() {

    override fun configureMessageBroker(config: MessageBrokerRegistry) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic")
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
    }

    override fun registerStompEndpoints(registry: StompEndpointRegistry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/websocket").withSockJS()
    }

}
```

**log:**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::             (v2.0.0.M7)

2018-02-22 16:54:41.188  INFO 5388 --- [           main] c.b.s.SmartHouseServerApplicationKt      : Starting SmartHouseServerApplicationKt on VKA with PID 5388 (D:\smart-house-server\target\classes started by vka in D:\smart-house-server)
2018-02-22 16:54:41.190  INFO 5388 --- [           main] c.b.s.SmartHouseServerApplicationKt      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-02-22 16:54:41.223  WARN 5388 --- [kground-preinit] o.s.h.c.j.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder    : For Jackson Kotlin classes support please add "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin" to the classpath
2018-02-22 16:54:41.234  INFO 5388 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@4fb61f4a: startup date [Thu Feb 22 16:54:41 EET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-02-22 16:54:41.381  WARN 5388 --- [kground-preinit] o.s.h.c.j.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder    : For Jackson Kotlin classes support please add "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin" to the classpath
2018-02-22 16:54:41.918 ERROR 5388 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:109) ~[spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:179) ~[spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141) ~[spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117) ~[spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:328) ~[spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233) ~[spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:693) ~[spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:138) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:751) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:387) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at com.bellkross.smarthouseserver.SmartHouseServerApplicationKt.main(SmartHouseServerApplication.kt:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:659) ~[spring-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:556) ~[spring-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:569) ~[spring-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:541) ~[spring-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:599) ~[spring-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:728) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:669) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:637) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1489) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1007) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:168) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:157) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary(BeanTypeRegistry.java:207) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.getNamesForType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:114) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:265) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:254) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:196) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:115) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/messaging/simp/user/SimpUserRegistry
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:641) ~[spring-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.messaging.simp.user.SimpUserRegistry
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    ... 39 common frames omitted

2018-02-22 16:54:41.924  INFO 5388 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@4fb61f4a: startup date [Thu Feb 22 16:54:41 EET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-02-22 16:54:41.926  WARN 5388 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Unable to close ApplicationContext

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:659) ~[spring-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:556) ~[spring-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:569) ~[spring-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:541) ~[spring-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:599) ~[spring-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:728) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:669) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:637) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1489) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:421) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:391) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:512) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1194) ~[spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:879) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:865) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:851) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:802) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at com.bellkross.smarthouseserver.SmartHouseServerApplicationKt.main(SmartHouseServerApplication.kt:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/messaging/simp/user/SimpUserRegistry
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:641) ~[spring-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.messaging.simp.user.SimpUserRegistry
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    ... 25 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.smth</groupId>
    <artifactId>smth</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <kotlin.compiler.incremental>true</kotlin.compiler.incremental>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.2.10</kotlin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jre8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- web socket -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

What's problem in my implementation?
(Sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem

spring-messaging version in maven was 4.0.0.RELEASE

after changing to 4.2.4RELEASE it started work

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the dependency below in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the following dependencies in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>stomp-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this fixed by changing out the `AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` with `WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer`. That's at least the takeaway I got from [reading the API documents.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE_to_5.0.3.RELEASE/Spring%20Framework%205.0.3.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer.html)

> in favor of simply using WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer which has default methods, made possible by a Java 8 baseline.